# Not able to format internal hard disk while installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I force shutdown my Ubuntu laptop and now ubuntu is not booting up. I tried reinstalling ubuntu and its not able to format the hard disk.

This is the error I am getting.

[image]

After clicking like 10 time on ignore these are two partitions its showing.

[image]

I am not able to delete the partition using Gparted. I am noob in ubuntu so not sure what to do?

Running following command via live USB.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo badblocks -nsv /dev/sda

/dev/sda is apparently in use by the system; it's not safe to run badblocks!
```

Another output which may be useful to debug:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: WDC PC SN520 SDAPMUW-256G-1001          
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 536144C8-7CBB-4497-A20D-C6D39DD7EABE

Device           Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 500117503 499066880  238G Linux filesystem
```

Some more data:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.98 GiB, 2103640064 bytes, 4108672 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 29.9 MiB, 31334400 bytes, 61200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 54.98 MiB, 57626624 bytes, 112552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 255.58 MiB, 267980800 bytes, 523400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 62.9 MiB, 65105920 bytes, 127160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 49.8 MiB, 52203520 bytes, 101960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: WDC PC SN520 SDAPMUW-256G-1001          
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 536144C8-7CBB-4497-A20D-C6D39DD7EABE

Device           Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 500117503 499066880  238G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 114.62 GiB, 123060879360 bytes, 240353280 sectors
Disk model: Ultra USB 3.0   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x56f48570

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          0   5439487   5439488  2.6G  0 Empty
/dev/sda2       5017392   5025327      7936  3.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda3       5439488 240353279 234913792  112G 83 Linux
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p2
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
fsck.ext2: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1p2

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

More Details:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sda3
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/sda3 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

More Details:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo e2fsck -f -b 32768 /dev/nvme0n1p2
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Error reading block 30965760 (Input/output error).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Superblock has an invalid journal (inode 8).
Clear<y>? yes
*** journal has been deleted ***

Superblock has_journal flag is clear, but a journal is present.
Clear<y>? yes
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Journal inode is not in use, but contains data.  Clear<y>? yes
Error reading block 6291570 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 6291597 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 6291718 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 6291719 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 1576532 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 1576538 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Error reading block 6815909 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes

Error reading block 7864841 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes

Error reading block 12058950 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 12058951 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 16253160 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 16253161 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 16253162 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 16253163 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 16253164 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 16253165 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 16253166 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 16253167 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 16253168 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 16253169 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 16253170 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 16253171 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 16253172 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 16253173 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 16253174 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 16253175 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes


Error reading block 24117297 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 24117658 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes


Error reading block 27263127 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Inode 6820975 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.




Inode 7869489 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.

Error reading block 31982810 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes

Error reading block 33554476 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 33554478 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 34603382 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 34603493 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 35651726 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 35651955 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes

Error reading block 37224639 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 38273066 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 38273078 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 39845934 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>?
```

.... Above command is continuing again and again..

Status of the two partitions that I see in Gparted.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Disk seems bad.. try `fsck` on the disk partitions see if that will help, if not, you are up for a new SSD :)

Comment: @Ron How did you figure that the NMVe is bad? There's not enough data for that conclusion.

Comment: I see the future :)

Comment: Its a month old laptop..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't manipulate your NVMe while you're booted to it.**

---

Let's check your file system and see if we can repair it.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
  <strike>- type `sudo fdisk -l`</strike>
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p2`<strike>, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier</strike>
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Return the laptop for warranty exchange at the location where purchased.

Comment: I have added the output.

Comment: @MohitJain Did you run `fsck` while booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? Also see Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: No. I didn't. I have updated the question as pe the update #1

Comment: @MohitJain Follow my instructions. **Step #1**. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Comment: I followed the commands and shared the output above.. sudo fdisk -l && sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p2

Comment: @MohitJain BUT... you didn't do **Step #1**.

Comment: An hour ago i ran this: Sudo badblocks -nsv /dev/nvme0n1 and it just completed with Pass completed, 1575692 bad blocks found. (1050380/0/525312 errors)

Comment: This one: boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode I am in that mode only.

Comment: @MohitJain Earlier I asked if you were booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, and your response was *"No. I didn't."*. Also, when fscking /dev/sda3, it says "mounted'. That shouldn't happen if you're booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Comment: @MohitJain And you shouldn't bad block a NVMe or SSD anyway.

Comment: @Heynema So sorry... I am in live mode but its saying mounted.

Comment: @MohitJain Let me clarify... you boot from the NVMe or the sda HDD?

Comment: I think i am not getting you. May be i don't know what exactly you are saying. I created a bootable pendrive and using bios settings I just booted from that pendrive. It showed me some options and I picked install ubuntu. Then there was two options try ubuntu or install ubuntu. I picked try ubuntu then I am trying all the commands via terminal.  Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112316/discussion-between-mohit-jain-and-heynnema).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm helping about 4 people at the same time... and I may be getting confused myself :-) My question was a general question about which device you normally boot from... the NVMe or the sda HDD? From the Ubuntu Live pen drive, can you get screenshots of `gparted` when viewing the NVMe, and also the sda?

Comment: From Gparted - from live pendrive this is what I see.https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoD3R.png only two partions thats it. I can't delete it. Mount option, by right click is disabled.

Comment: I'm in chat....

Comment: @heynema I just checked with the service center, They are replacing the hard drive. It was an issue with SSD. Thank you for all your help.